# Kotlin EditText show/hide password programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I know how to do this on Java.
I copied and paste the code from Java to Kotlin and Android Studio changed to this:

```
auth_password_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```

But I'm receiving a message (grey not yellow like warning)
[image]

I search and found only java and react native answer but not was the best/right way to do this in Kotlin.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any warning or suggestion reported by the IDE, you can press Alt-Enter, and in most cases (including this one) the IDE will suggest a quickfix that will automatically apply the suggested change.

In this case, it will change the call of a Java setter to a Kotlin property access:

```
auth_password_text.inputType = ...
```

Comment: I tried to use the Alt+enter (click on the yellow light) before, but it changed other stuff, but work like a charm. Thanks. Just waiting for the time to tick as right!

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin you can set some properties accessing directly variable instead of calling setter method, that's the meaning of the warning you are getting.

You can remove warning like this:

```
auth_password_text.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly this.